# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS using IIS is not working for SharePoint Site

Tags: iis, redirect, https, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a Web Application. Its AAM is as follows-

```
Zone         Public URL for Zone
Default      http://sharepoint:46543
Internet     http://abc.something.com
Custom       https://abc.something.com
```

Before using IIS Rewrite module, if I access the site from any Zone it works fine.

But once I configure Rewrite module as following-

***Match URL Section***

```
Requested URL               = Matches the Pattren
Using                       = Regular Expression
Pattren = (.*)
```

***Conditioins***

```
Logical Grouping            = Match All
Condition Input             = {HTTPS}
Check if input string       = Matches the pattren
Pattren                     = ^OFF$
```

***Actions***

```
Action Type                  = Redirect
Redirect URL                 = https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}
Append Query String          = True
Redirect Type                = See Other (303)
```

If I try to access the site on the `Web Front Server` i.e. using Default Zone `http://sharepoint:46543` the website does not open. Even Central Administration stop opening at this time.

If I try to access Internet Zone `http://abc.something.com` then it gets redirected to Custom Zone `https://abc.something.com` but it does not open the site. Even if I try to access Custom Zone site by directly entering the URL, it does not open.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The configuration looks correct.  The only difference I have is the Redirect type as a Found(302).

Your testing on the server - by default you won't be able to access due to the loop back check. in Registry `HKEY_LM\System\CCS\Control\LSA\MSV1.0` find the `BackConnectionsHostsNames` multi string value and enter the name of your share point site there (abc.something.com)

If your test is failing from off-box, it's not the loop back.  In this case ensure Firewall is allowing requests, IIS bindings are configured for both port 80 and 443 (and certificate is assigned).  If you have multiple sites listening on same IP/Port you have to use host headers or IIS will not start all of the sites.